# Github access error

Tags: github

I went to GitHub url and created a repo called demo_app
Then in terminal I said

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:babakinks/demo_app.git
```

and then I said:

```
git push -u origin master
```

but its error message says:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

So I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You might need to specify a protocol, maybe. `ssh://git@github.com/babakinks/demo_app.git`. I'm not sure. Do you want to use public key authentication, or your GitHub username and password? If it's the latter, use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the SSH method of server access but your private key isn't matching the servers public key. Notice the 'publickey' in brackets after the 'Permission denied' message. You need to generate a key pair.

Github has a tutorial that explains it much better than I can: [Link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Alternativly, like minitech said, you can use HTTPS authentication that is easier and uses your username and password. See the screenshot below, if you click HTTP and use the given link it should use HTTPS authentication.

[image: HTTP Authentication Option]

Answer (score 1):

`git@github.com:babakinks/demo_app.git` uses SSH to do connection, so you need a key pair. [REFER IT HERE](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

If `babakinks` isn't you, you need to fork `git@github.com:babakinks/demo_app.git` as your own `git@github.com:<your_username>/demo_app.git` then do push jobs.

After that, you can send **Pull Request** to the author to merge your commmits.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I fixed it but not sure how did it got fixed!

I downloaded the GitHub for Mac app form here  http://mac.github.com and opened it and refresh it and it showed my demo_app repo.
Then again I ran the same command line that I had ran before for push master and this time it worked.

But I don't know the technical reason behind it.